# How do I increase the RAM and set up host-only networking in Vagrant?

Tags: networking, configuration, vagrant

I would like to increase the RAM to at least 1 GB and I would like to configure “Host-Only” networking to use "199.188.44.20".

This is my `Vagrantfile`:

```rb
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant::Config.run do |config|

    config.vm.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 1024]

    config.vm.network :hostonly, "199.188.44.20"

    config.vm.define :web do |web_config|
        web_config.vm.box = "lucid32"
        web_config.vm.forward_port 80, 8080

        web_config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
            puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
            puppet.manifest_file = "lucid32.pp"
        end
    end

    config.vm.define :web2 do |web2_config| 
        web2_config.vm.box = "lucid32"
        web2_config.vm.forward_port 80, 8081

        web2_config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
            puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
            puppet.manifest_file = "myweb.pp"
        end
    end
end
```

However, when I run `vagrant up` I am getting:

> *The VM failed to remain in the "running" state while attempting to boot. This is normally cause by a misconfiguration or host system incompatibles. Please open the VirtualBox GUI and attempt to boot the virtual machine manually to get more informative error message*

And, I am getting a `connection refuse` error when I try to log in to the VM.

Comment: Increasing RAM might help when you get "Killed" message.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can modify various VM properties by adding the following configuration ([see the Vagrant docs for a bit more info](http://vagrantup.com/v1/docs/config/vm/customize.html)):

```
  # Configure VM Ram usage
  config.vm.customize [
                        "modifyvm", :id,
                        "--name", "Test_Environment",
                        "--memory", "1024"
                      ]
```

You can obtain the properties that you want to change from the documents for VirtualBox command-line options:

- http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html#vboxmanage-modifyvm

The [vagrant documentation](http://vagrantup.com/v1/docs/host_only_networking.html) has the section on how to change IP address:

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.network :hostonly, "192.168.50.4"
end
```

Also you can restructure the configuration like this, ending is do with end without nesting it.
This is simpler.

```
config.vm.define :web do |web_config|
    web_config.vm.box = "lucid32"
    web_config.vm.forward_port 80, 8080
end
web_config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
    puppet.manifest_file = "lucid32.pp"
end
```

Answer (score 161):

To increase the memory or CPU count when using Vagrant 2, add this to your Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
    # usual vagrant config here

    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        v.memory = 1024
        v.cpus = 2
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! One must remember to do `vagrant halt` and `vagrant up` to restart the machine with the new settings.  It is not sufficient to do `vagrant suspend`. Could be useful for (* cough *) someone to know...

Comment: You can also do `vagrant reload`

Comment: For reference purposes: https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/virtualbox/configuration.html

Comment: You can write in this way too  config.vm.provider :virtualbox

Answer (score 96):

Since `Vagrant 1.1` `customize` option is getting VirtualBox-specific.

The modern way to do it is:

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|
  vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "256"]
end
```

Comment: You can also use `vagrant up --provider=virtualbox` per http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/providers/basic_usage.html

Comment: By _modern way_ you mean `VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"`, as described in the [Vagrant docs](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/vagrantfile/version.html)

Answer (score 7):

I could not get any of these answers to work. Here's what I ended up putting at the very top of my Vagrantfile, before the `Vagrant::Config.run do` block:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "1024"]
  end
end
```

I noticed that the shortcut accessor style, "vb.memory = 1024", didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 5):

You can easily increase your VM's RAM by modifying the memory property of config.vm.provider section in your vagrant file.

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
 vb.memory = "4096"
end
```

This allocates about 4GB of RAM to your VM. You can change this according to your requirement. For example, following setting would allocate 2GB of RAM to your VM.

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
 vb.memory = "2048"
end
```

Try removing the `config.vm.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 1024]` in your file, and adding the above code.

For the network configuration, try modifying the `config.vm.network :hostonly, "199.188.44.20"` in your file to`config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "199.188.44.20"`