# increasing the memory for an ipython notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I am using ipython notebook and am using up too much memory.

Using:
`ps -e -orss=,args= | sort -b -k1,1n | pr -TW$COLUMNS | tail -n 10`
I see it come up to a little over 200MB before restarting the kernel.

I read [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/ptwobrussell/Mining-the-Social-Web-2nd-Edition/master/ipynb/_Appendix%20C%20-%20Python%20&%20IPython%20Notebook%20Tips.ipynb) that I should increase the memory for the virtual box of the notebook with vagrant. However, I am not using Vagrant, and running ipython notebook from my shell without any virtual box (that I am aware of).

What do I do to increase the memory allocation?

Comment: `iPython notebook` can be used in a vagrant/vbox setup but it doesn't have to be. I think you wondered into some inappropriate documentation. I assume by `restarting the kernel` you mean restarted by the kernel. If the kernel is killing your process you need to find out why and 200mb doesn't sound like a very good reason to kill a proc. Check your `/var/log/syslog` for events at the time your proc was killed it could be related to `ulimit`s

Comment: @nsfyn55 I think he meant restarting the __ipython__ kernel. Ipython, like python, will use as much memory as it needs. If it's using too much, chances are you've got variables etc.. that use lots of memory. Thinkgs like matplotlib plots also eat up memory.

Comment: Well if the only question is how to I increase memory allocation for vagrant(and by extension the underlying vbox image) then I vote to close cause this has to have been answered somewhere on SO(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12308149/vagrantfile-how-do-i-increase-ram-and-set-up-host-only-networking).

Comment: Or wait OP isn't even using vagrant. Its just poorly tagged.