# Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "/home/vagrant/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/protobuf-0.5.3"

Tags: vagrant, dart, dart-pub

I'm trying to build a Dart project from inside a Vagrant VM. The project was actually created from my host machine using IntelliJ, but I would like that whoever uses the Vagrant VM is of course able to build the project (and in general do everything it's possible to do with a Dart project using the Dart tools), which is the main reason why I set up a Vagrant VM to develop.

So (as usual in a Vagrant environment) in my guest machine, the path `/vagrant` contains files which are the same (and synchronized) with the files where the `Vagrantfile` is located on my host machine.

My Dart project was created in the host machine under the folder `dart-angular-client`, which is at the same level as the `Vagrantfile`. I'm able to build the project from my host machine from inside `dart-angular-client` and from IntelliJ, but the idea was to be able to build the project from inside the Vagrant machine.

So, when I try to type `pub build` under `/vagrant/dart-angular-client` of my guest Vagrant VM, I obtain the following error

```
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "/home/vagrant/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/protobuf-0.5.3"
```

where `/home/vagrant/` is basically the home directory of the guest Vagrant VM. I tried to install manually and globally a Dart package from inside the guest machine, and the package was indeed installed under `/home/vagrant/.pub-cache`, as one would expect, since (as far as I know) Dart packages that are installed/activated globally are put under that folder (even in my host machine).

How can I build my project from inside the Vagrant VM?

---

#### Edit

After doing `pub get` (as suggested by Günter Zöchbauer), when I run the command `pub build` now I obtain

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/dart-angular-client$ pub build
Loading source assets... 
Loading angular2/transform/codegen and dart_to_js_script_rewriter transformers... 
Loading angular2 transformers... (6.5s)Dumping native stack trace for thread c36
  [0x000000000091a708] dart::WeakTable::SetValue(dart::RawObject*, long)
  [0x000000000091a708] dart::WeakTable::SetValue(dart::RawObject*, long)
  [0x00000000008c3e20] dart::Scavenger::ProcessWeakReferences()
  [0x00000000008c464f] dart::Scavenger::Scavenge(bool)
  [0x00000000006f0298] dart::Heap::CollectNewSpaceGarbage(dart::Thread*, dart::Heap::ApiCallbacks, dart::Heap::GCReason)
  [0x00000000006f0cc8] dart::Heap::AllocateNew(long)
  [0x000000000078baf8] dart::Object::Allocate(long, long, dart::Heap::Space)
  [0x00000000007aadc3] dart::TypedData::New(long, long, dart::Heap::Space)
  [0x0000000000aeaf69] dart::BootstrapNatives::DN_TypedData_Uint8Array_new(_Dart_NativeArguments*)
  [0x00007f0cb907e579] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cb737e97d] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cab554524] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cab5534ee] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cab552588] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cab551e6d] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cb601dfba] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cab551a53] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cab54f4e9] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cab50fde3] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0caeb01d4d] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cb6c78cb0] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cb52c198f] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cb6c7a97e] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cab56cf92] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cab58165a] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0caeaee66d] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cab581ff7] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cab51bba1] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0caeb01d4d] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cb6c78cb0] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cb52c198f] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cb6c7a97e] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cab56cf92] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cab58165a] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0caeaee66d] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cab581ff7] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cab52c77b] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0caeb01d4d] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cb6c78cb0] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cb52c198f] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cb6c7a97e] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cab56cf92] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cab58165a] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0caeaee66d] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cab5389f0] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cb6c80a6d] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cb6c8048c] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cb30900bd] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0caeaebbe4] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0caeafbd71] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0caeafe6b8] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cb6c80a6d] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cb6c8048c] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cb30900bd] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cb6c915c2] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cb6c80ae9] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cb6c8048c] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cb30900bd] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cb6c915c2] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cab582b12] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cb651de80] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0caeaf2520] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cab58756e] Unknown symbol
  [0x00007f0cb907e836] Unknown symbol
  [0x000000000064e2f0] dart::DartEntry::InvokeFunction(dart::Function const&, dart::Array const&, dart::Array const&)
  [0x00000000006521bd] dart::DartLibraryCalls::HandleMessage(dart::Object const&, dart::Instance const&)
  [0x000000000074f4e8] dart::IsolateMessageHandler::HandleMessage(dart::Message*)
  [0x000000000077124a] dart::MessageHandler::HandleMessages(dart::MonitorLocker*, bool, bool)
  [0x00000000007715e1] dart::MessageHandlerTask::Run()
-- End of DumpStackTrace
```

which seems a little bit more severe. I'm not sure what caused this problem (pub, Vagrant, etc), but that seems C++ code. This looks like some stack corruption... This happened after having built the project from the host machine, but (as far as I've understood) the `build` (if it exists) is replaced whenever we try to rebuild the Dart project.

#### Edit 2

I retried to `reload` and `provision` the virtual machine again, and then I ssh inside it, and I tried to `build` the Dart project again, and this was similarly the result:

```
Loading source assets... 
Loading angular2/transform/codegen and dart_to_js_script_rewriter transformers... 
Loading angular2 transformers... (7.3s)runtime/vm/scavenger.cc: 399: error: Out of memory.
Dumping native stack trace for thread 9f9
(7.4s)  [0x000000000087b7ee] dart::Profiler::DumpStackTrace()
  [0x000000000087b7ee] dart::Profiler::DumpStackTrace()
  [0x00000000005c8f5d] dart::DynamicAssertionHelper::Fail(char const*, ...)
  [0x00000000008c353d] dart::Scavenger::Prologue(dart::Isolate*, bool)
  [0x00000000008c43e6] dart::Scavenger::Scavenge(bool)
  [0x00000000006f0298] dart::Heap::CollectNewSpaceGarbage(dart::Thread*, dart::Heap::ApiCallbacks, dart::Heap::GCReason)
  [0x00000000006f0cc8] dart::Heap::AllocateNew(long)
  [0x000000000078baf8] dart::Object::Allocate(long, long, dart::Heap::Space)
  [0x000000000078bca8] Unknown symbol
  [0x00000000006520cf] dart::DartLibraryCalls::HandleMessage(dart::Object const&, dart::Instance const&)
  [0x000000000074f4e8] dart::IsolateMessageHandler::HandleMessage(dart::Message*)
  [0x000000000077124a] dart::MessageHandler::HandleMessages(dart::MonitorLocker*, bool, bool)
  [0x00000000007715e1] dart::MessageHandlerTask::Run()
-- End of DumpStackTrace
Aborted (core dumped)
```

#### Edit 3

Not even having destroyed and `vagrant up` the VM, it seems to have changed something, since I obtained:

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/vagrant/dart-angular-client$ pub build
Loading source assets... 
Loading angular2/transform/codegen and dart_to_js_script_rewriter transformers... 
Loading angular2 transformers... (11.8s)runtime/vm/scavenger.cc: 399: error: Out of memory.
Dumping native stack trace for thread 2646
  [0x000000000087b7ee] dart::Profiler::DumpStackTrace()
(17.0s)  [0x000000000087b7ee] dart::Profiler::DumpStackTrace()
  [0x00000000005c8f5d] dart::DynamicAssertionHelper::Fail(char const*, ...)
  [0x00000000008c353d] dart::Scavenger::Prologue(dart::Isolate*, bool)
  [0x00000000008c43e6] dart::Scavenger::Scavenge(bool)
  [0x00000000006f0298] dart::Heap::CollectNewSpaceGarbage(dart::Thread*, dart::Heap::ApiCallbacks, dart::Heap::GCReason)
  [0x00000000006f09b9] dart::Heap::AllocateOld(long, dart::HeapPage::PageType)
(17.6s)  [0x000000000078ba67] dart::Object::Allocate(long, long, dart::Heap::Space)
  [0x000000000078bca8] Unknown symbol
  [0x00000000007d2c2b] dart::HashMap<dart::UnorderedHashTable<dart::CompressedTokenTraits, 1l> >::InsertOrGetValue(dart::Object const&, dart::Object const&) const
  [0x00000000007d31e8] dart::CompressedTokenStreamData::AddToken(dart::Scanner::TokenDescriptor const&)
Killed
```

Comment: Sounds like you are missing a `pub get` command or `/home/vagrant/.pub-cache` is somehow corrupt. Are you sure (if you actually run `pub get`) that the command was completed before `pub build` is run? Is this `.pub-cache` directory recreated every time before you build in vagrant, or is a previous version kept? (I don't know Vagrant)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Oh, since I'm very new to Dart (I still need to learn the language), I didn't know I had to do `pub get` manually, I thought `pub build` would have performed that automatically in case the dependencies were not resolved..

Comment: No. `pub get` needs to be called explicitly. You need that already during development - for example in WebStorm to get auto-completion for imported code.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Ok, thanks. See my edit, please.

Comment: Are you using the same Dart version in Vagrant as on your host machine? What version is it?

Comment: Yes, the `build` directory is purged as first step of a `pub build` run.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer This is what I obtain when I type `dart --version` on my host machine: `Dart VM version: 1.21.1 (Fri Jan 13 01:40:43 2017) on "macos_x64"` and this is what I obtain when I'm inside the guest VM: `Dart VM version: 1.21.1 (Fri Jan 13 09:44:01 2017) on "linux_x64"`.

Comment: "Out of memory" seems pretty clear ;-)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes, I will try to destroy and _up_ the Vagrant VM again and see if this happens again...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12308149/how-do-i-increase-the-ram-and-set-up-host-only-networking-in-vagrant might help (just did a search and posted the first link)

Answer (score 0):

- ensure `pub get` is run before `pub build`
- ensure the virtual machine has enough RAM (see also [How do I increase the RAM and set up host-only networking in Vagrant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12308149/how-do-i-increase-the-ram-and-set-up-host-only-networking-in-vagrant))

Comment: Yes, essentially combining these two solutions in order solved both respectively the first and the second problem.